# Having trouble with ObserveObject Array changes in my code

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift4, swift5

Currently, my code finds nearby parks around the user's current location and outputs the name/location in the console fine (using Google Maps & Google Places API).
[Console Output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCvAE.png)
The next step I'm trying to complete in my app is to annotate each one of these parks on the map with a marker in the GoogleMapsView.swift file before I return the mapView. My issue is that I can't figure out how to do this **after** the park locations are found. So my question is how can I observe the park location changes in the array to be able to mark them on the map afterwards? Here is the code I have. In my ContentView.swift, I simply pass the GoogleMapsView into view.

**PlacesManager.swift:**

```
import GooglePlaces

class PlacesManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, LocationManagerDelegate {
    
    @Published var places = [Place]()
    lazy var googleClient: GoogleClientRequest = GoogleClient()
    var locationManager: LocationManager?
    var searchRadius : Int = 700
        
    override init() {
        super.init()
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {
        locationManager = LocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
    }
    
    func locationDidChange(location: CLLocation) {
        let lat = location.coordinate.latitude
        let long = location.coordinate.longitude
        let newLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        
        fetchGoogleData(forLocation: newLocation, searchRadius: 700)
    }
    
    func fetchGoogleData(forLocation: CLLocation, searchRadius: Int) {
        //guard let location = currentLocation else { return }
        googleClient.getGooglePlacesData(location: forLocation, withinMeters: searchRadius) { (response) in
            self.places = response.results

        }
    }
    
    //... print parks in console code is here
}
```

**LocationManager.swift:**

```
protocol LocationManagerDelegate: class {
    func locationDidChange(location: CLLocation)
}

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    weak var delegate: LocationManagerDelegate?
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    @Published var location: CLLocation? {
        willSet { objectWillChange.send() }
    }
    
    var latitude: CLLocationDegrees {
        return location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0
    }
    
    var longitude: CLLocationDegrees {
        return location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0
    }
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        
        if status == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        guard status == .authorizedWhenInUse else {
            return
        }
        
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.first else {
            return
        }
        
        self.location = location
        self.delegate?.locationDidChange(location: location)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

**GoogleMapsView.swift:**

```
struct GoogleMapsView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    @ObservedObject var place: PlacesManager = PlacesManager()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> GMSMapView {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: locationManager.latitude, longitude: locationManager.longitude, zoom: 15)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.rotateGestures = false
        mapView.settings.tiltGestures = false
        mapView.isIndoorEnabled = false
        mapView.isTrafficEnabled = false
        mapView.isBuildingsEnabled = false
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

        return mapView
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing question  plus too much code

Comment: @FeridunErbaş The question is right there, please try to be helpful

Comment: I remember Google Places API does not fully support SwiftUI yet, it won't update the map automatically after the observed array changed. Instead you need to re render the map view every time you added or removed new marker on the map.

Comment: @Bryce Do you know how to do this or have a link to an updated tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

In my project I used UIKit to handle the map and marker, the approach is quite different from what you posted. Anyway here is one of the function I used to "refresh" the map after I updated the marker from the Place API, hope it helps~

```
func addMarkerFrom(places: [Place]) {
    for place in places {
        if place.user_ratings_total ?? 100 > UInt(100) && place.business_status == "OPERATIONAL" {
            if place.types?.contains(where: placeTypesFilter.contains) == false {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let marker = GMSMarker()
                    let fetchedPlace = place
                    let markerIconImage = UIImage(named: "Marker_icon_blue")
                    
                    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (fetchedPlace.geometry?.location?.latitude)!, longitude: (fetchedPlace.geometry?.location?.longitude)!)
                    marker.title = place.name
                    marker.snippet = "\(String(describing: fetchedPlace.user_ratings_total)), \(String(describing: fetchedPlace.rating))"
                    marker.appearAnimation = .pop
                    marker.icon = self.drawMarkerWith(image: markerIconImage!, rating: fetchedPlace.rating!, userRatingTool: fetchedPlace.user_ratings_total!)
                    marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 2.3)
                    marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true
                    marker.map = self.mapView
                    filteredPlaces.append(fetchedPlace)
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```